# 2sxc: Linking to Permission Locked Resources

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

We are running into an issue where the link generated by 2sxc when linking to documents that are housed within a protected directory are pointing to an invalid link.

Example:
/Root/Member Resources/Example.pdf

If the **Member Resources** directory is locked to users with a specific role, the 2sxc document manager folder will correctly map to the resources within file file manager viewer, however the link rendered on page load is linking to Example.pdf where it should link to something like: /LinkClick.aspx?fileticket=8wCAB4arm_8%3d&portalid=0

I tried modifying the Server Resource References setting in the Advanced settings for the field manager (which tells 2sxc to either use a file:0000 value or actual link) and that did not seem to modify the output type/format.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow :)
We at 2sic (the makers of 2sxc) don't often use protected resources, so this may be an oversight on our side, but AFAIK, quite a lot of people use it so it must work.

I believe something like this should actually do the trick (not tested...):

```
// assuming your item is called Content
// and the file field is called CaseStudy
```

```
<a 
  href="@DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.LinkClick(Content.CaseStudy, Dnn.TabId, Dnn.ModuleId,false)">
  download
</a>
```

Comment: Using this markup on DNN v9.02.02 and 2sxc v9.43.1 gives me an error: 'ToSic.SexyContent.Razor.Helpers.DnnHelper' does not contain a definition for 'TabId' and no extension method 'TabId' accepting a first argument of type...  

By replacing DNN.TabId and Dnn.ModuleID to the token provided in the DNN Snippets I get the following markup:  

@DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.LinkClick(Content.LinkURL, Dnn.Module.TabID, Dnn.Module.ModuleID,false)  

This will output the URL, but not the protected URL. The link takes the user to the "The resource you are looking for has been removed" page.

Comment: The 2sxc content field does not work. Content.CaseStudy seems to only want to output the actual rendered link for the file. This causes conflict because LinkClick is looking for fileID=2083.

When I hard-code fileID=2083, I'm able to get the correct LinkClick path. However it is completely bypassing the DNN authentication and will let a non-authenticated user to download the file.

Comment: Ok. I assume you made the issue on Github, we'll look into it.

Comment: BTW: Fixed in 2sxc 10.20